# spring integration jsonignore properties

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to ignore some json information that I receive from JMS:

```
{"publishedDate":"2018","title":"How to","author":"rcade"}
```

I am using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"title", "author", "publishedDate"})
public class Posts {
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties({"publishedDate"})
    private String title;
    private String author;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}

public class JsonToPojoTransformerBean {

    public Posts transform(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull Message message) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Posts result = mapper.readValue(message.getPayload().toString(), Posts.class);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to insert them.

```
 <int:transformer id="jsonToProdObjectTransformer" ref="JsonToPojoTransformerBean" input-channel="JmsInbound"
                     method="transform" output-channel="feed"/>

<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter id="jdbcOutbound"
                                       channel="feed"
                                       data-source="dataSource"
                                       query="INSERT INTO posts(title, author)
                                       values(:payload[title], :payload[author])"/>
```

But as always I am getting errors:

```
Invalid property 'payload[title]' of bean class [org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage]: Illegal attempt to get property 'payload' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'payload[title]' of bean class [org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'payload[title]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Set nor a Map; returned value was [com.example.Posts@76038c44]
```

This is first time I am trying this and why it doesn't work as a `payload[title]`? How do I need provide these values for `query`? Have I done this even correctly for ignoring some of the json payload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fully not clear how that `@JsonIgnoreProperties` subject is related to the exception about wrong SpEL expression, but I leave it for you to decide.

So, what we have so far is:

1. Spring Integration in the expression parts deal with the `Message` as an evaluation context root object. The `Message` has contract like:

   ```
   public interface Message<T> {

    /**
     * Return the message payload.
     */
    T getPayload();

    /**
     * Return message headers for the message (never {@code null} but may be empty).
     */
    MessageHeaders getHeaders();

   }
   ```

therefore we can do `headers` and `payload` in the expression as a reference to those getters of the root object.

2. The payload in your is that `Posts` object. Which is really not a list or array or even map to do a `[]` (index) operator on it.
3. To get access to those `title` and `author` you just need to follow a getter rule in SpEL. Therefore the same plain dot operator with the property name: `values(:payload.title, :payload.author)`.

If that doesn't work, you need to think about injecting an `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` into that `<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>` with parameter name aliases to the target expressions.

See some ideas in the samples project: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jdbc.

Also docs give some explanations, too: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter

Comment: Thank you again. Yea I messed up there with ```@JsonIgnoreProperties``` but now got everything working as I expected.